# Is there a way to delete a locked file on windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-permissions

I am trying to delete a file generated during my eclipse (Java) build. I have been carefully reading all of the answers from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/2937/how-do-i-delete-a-folder-thats-in-use), but none work for me so far (see below).

The file is called dataentry.war. I used [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) to identify the process owning it:

```
> handle64 dataentry.war
Nthandle v4.1 - Handle viewer
Copyright (C) 1997-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
ccSvcHst.exe       pid: 2720   type: File          2350: C:\Users\mmalaterre\workspace\dataentry\target\dataentry.war

ccSvcHst.exe       pid: 2720   type: File          2350: C:\Users\mmalaterre\workspace\dataentry\target\dataentry.war

ccSvcHst.exe       pid: 2720   type: File          344C: C:\Users\mmalaterre\workspace\dataentry\target\dataentry.war

ccSvcHst.exe       pid: 2720   type: File          344C: C:\Users\mmalaterre\workspace\dataentry\target\dataentry.war
```

So now how do I delete this file ?

Using `explorer` (started with admin rights), I get this dumb message that I do not have admin rights:

[image]

I tried using the task manager:

[image]

but this lead to:

[image]

From a `cmd` shell with administrator right:

```
>del /F dataentry.war
c:\Users\mmalaterre\workspace\dataentry\target\dataentry.war
Access is denied.
```

For some reason I cannot get `resmon` to find the handle:

[image]

I also tried renaming the parent directory so that it is not in my way (eclipse), but again I cannot do it:

[image]

If I try to delete the process from a cmd (with admin rights), here is what I get:

```
>taskkill /PID 2720 /t /f
ERROR: The process with PID 3856 (child process of PID 2720) could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.
ERROR: The process with PID 2720 (child process of PID 700) could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.
```

Is there **any** way to delete a locked file on windows ?

Comment: "Is there any way to delete a file on windows?" - Of course just place the file in the recycle bin.  ""Is there any way to delete a locked file on windows?" - Identify the process that has locked the file.  Just because you have Administrator rights does not mean, your Administrator user, is in the file's ACL.  You should edit your question, because the question you asked appears to be difference, from the question you actual want to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your virusscanner is locking the file and the virusscanner is pretty well protected against killing the process, to prevent a virus trying to do the same thing.

Stop the real-time virusscanner temporarily to remove the lock. If that doesn't work reboot to remove the lock.
Then delete the file.

P.S. It is generally a good idea to exclude your compile/build/debug directory from the real-time virusscanner. The actions of a compiler/linker/debugger can look suspicious to a virusscanner and excessive checks by the virusscanner can really slow down or even interfere with a compile/build/debug session.

Comment: In worse case scenario, reboot into Safe Mode, then delete and then reboot again.