# SEP: Excluding files/folders from scheduled scans

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, anti-virus

I am trying to exclude files/folders from scheduled scans to prevent them from being locked (as described in my [previous post](https://superuser.com/questions/1156495/is-there-a-way-to-delete-a-locked-file-on-windows)). So I've carefully followed instructions [from here](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH91951.html):

> How to set up Exclusions for an Unmanaged Client: Open the Symantec
>   Endpoint Protection Client interface. Select "Change Settings" from
>   the left-hand column. Select Configure Settings for "Antivirus and
>   Antispyware Protection." Select the "File System Auto-Protect" tab.
>   Select the Centralized Exceptions button. Select Add and select the
>   desired exclusion type and enter in your exclusion.

However it seems this is rather an old document and is not accurate for newer Symantec Endpoint Protection UI (as seen [here for example](https://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/excluding-filesfolders-scheduled-scans#comment-11136281)). None of the options listed above seems to be available for me:

[image: Change Settings]

No such things as Centralized exceptions here:

[image: Virus Spyware Protection]

All Exceptions menu are grayed out:

[image: Exceptions 1]

[image: Exceptions 2]

How can I exclude file/folders from scheduled scans in Symantec Endpoint Protection version 12.1.6 (12.1 RU6) build 6168 ?

[image: Version]

---

UPDATE: I am running SymCorpUI as admin:

[image: SymCorpUI as Admin]

It appears that I am running a managed client ([ref](https://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/determine-if-managed-or-unmanaged-client#comment-1320271)):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you run this using Symantec Endpoint Protection Management Server? The lock symbols would indicate that.

An Exception policy could contain those folders and would also decide whenever or not you're able to define individual exceptions. If you DO have such a policy in place make sure you run the UI as the Administration.

You can find the `SymCorpUI.exe` in the following folder if you have no shortcut available: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\<Version>\Bin`

Comment: It does not seems to make any difference running the process as administrator.

Comment: So is it a managed client? In that case the policy probably doesn't allow you to setup exclusions.